# Understanding how sprintf converts integers to strings

Tags: c, printf

I am in the process of learning C and on a basic example of converting integers to string (which you take for granted in other languages). The answer I found was this:

```
sprintf(str, "%d", num);
```

But I would like to see how this is implemented. So I look up [sprintf](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/sprintf.c) and it takes me here:

```
#define vsprintf(s, f, a) _IO_vsprintf (s, f, a)

int
__sprintf (char *s, const char *format, ...)
{
  va_list arg;
  int done;

  va_start (arg, format);
  done = vsprintf (s, format, arg);
  va_end (arg);

  return done;
}
```

So then I look up [`_IO_vsprintf`](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/libio/iovsprintf.c) and it shows:

```
int
__IO_vsprintf (char *string, const char *format, va_list args)
{
  _IO_strfile sf;
  int ret;

#ifdef _IO_MTSAFE_IO
  sf._sbf._f._lock = NULL;
#endif
  _IO_no_init (&sf._sbf._f, _IO_USER_LOCK, -1, NULL, NULL);
  _IO_JUMPS (&sf._sbf) = &_IO_str_jumps;
  _IO_str_init_static_internal (&sf, string, -1, string);
  ret = _IO_vfprintf (&sf._sbf._f, format, args);
  _IO_putc_unlocked ('\0', &sf._sbf._f);
  return ret;
}
```

Which seems to revolve around `_IO_vfprintf`. But I can't find where that is in the [code](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/tree/master/libio). Google and GitHub bring no results. Wondering if anyone has the full implementation of sprintf available or if not, can explain how it works.

I would like to know how to implement itoa as sprintf does it, which sounds like is a good implementation.

I am confused as to how this code can actually run if there is no implementation.

Comment: Look for `vfprintf` instead.

Comment: What is the corresponding int to string with `vfprintf` then.

Comment: `vfprintf` leads to `__nldbl_vfprintf` which leads to blank as well. Actually maybe [this](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c#L1238).

Comment: Anyway, if you want an `itoa` functionality, the `xprintf` is a serious overkill to look at. There is an `strtol` family that is performing better than any of these.

Comment: Does it have the buffer overflow problem?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "buffer overflow problem". C in general has a "buffer overflow problem" in a sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190377/discussion-between-lance-pollard-and-eugene-sh).

Comment: Not sure where the string to integer form of `strtol` is either.

Comment: `printf` in glibc is a function that was hand optimized by generations, it uses many features, that if you can't simply find [_IO_vfprintf](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c#L2362).... I suggest you start with something simpler, at least not with glibc printf, but with for example [newlib printf](https://github.com/eblot/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/stdio/vfprintf.c#L1593).

Comment: Bear in mind, this is a function of *this specific implementation* (compiler) - it's not going to be universal to all C implementations.  Exactly how `*printf` formats *anything* is left up to the implementation, as long as it satisfies the requirements in the standard.  The exact source may not even be made available to end users of the compiler.

Comment: @EugeneSh. — `strtol()` is the inverse of the `itoa()` or `*printf()` family, isn't it, converting a string to an integer, rather than formatting an integer into a string.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh my. Got confused completely. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Looks](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c#L2363) like `_IO_vfprintf` is a hidden alias to `_IO_vfprintf_internal`.

When compiling the file `vfprintf.c` file for normal (not wide) characters, the `fprintf` becomes a macro defined as `_IO_vfprintf_internal`, from [here](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c#L81) and undefined before aliasing [here](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c#L2355).

So `_IO_vfprintf_internal` declaration starts [here](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c#L1238), where `vfprintf` is declared (well, "in un-proprocessed source file", the identifier `vfprintf` get's never declared).

After the `vfprintf` functions stopped processing all the width, spaces, minuses and other format specifiers, it finally will jump through [jump tables](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c#L272) (that basically is a smart way of jumping around to different `goto` labels by a jump table with addresses obtained through GCC extensions [labels as values](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html)) it will land on [`form_integer:`](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c#L487) label. From there we [jump](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c#L535) to [`number:`](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c#L627). From there we call [`_itoa_word`](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c#L648).

Now [_itoa_word](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/_itoa.c#L173) is plainly simple and easy, even enough to post here the preprocessed function:

```
char *
_itoa_word (_ITOA_WORD_TYPE value, char *buflim,
        unsigned int base, int upper_case) {
        const char *digits = (upper_case
               ? _itoa_upper_digits
               : _itoa_lower_digits);

      ...
      switch (base)
      {
      ...
      // SPECIAL (10); expands to:
      case 10:
          do
              *--buflim = digits[value % Base];
          while ((value /= Base) != 0);
          break;
      ...
      }
      ...
}
```

Where the `digits`, as in [_itoa_upper_digits](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/itoa-udigits.c#L22) or as in [_itoa_lower_digits](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/itoa-digits.c) is a simple lookup table, a char array initialized from a string literal, used to convert decimals to their associated ascii representation.

After `_itoa_word` there some code for handling left justifing the string, printing the leading sign character and padding the string with spaces or zeros, but finally our string gets [outputted](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c#L697) (or left justified [outputted](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c#L736)).

> example of converting integers to string

So 99% of the work is for handling all the strange

```
printf("%+- 3lld %+- 4.3Lf %-+04hhd %+- 5zd", 1llu, 2.L, 3, (ssize_t)4);
```

format specifiers it needs to conform to. The conversion is just a simple conversion using a lookup string (to handle non-ASCII systems) that work's it's way backwards through the number:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *my_itoa(char *dest, size_t destlen, int number)
{
    // we will work our way from the ending
    char *p = &dest[destlen];
    // null terminate the string
    *--p = '\0';

    while (number) {
        if (p == dest) {
            // destination buffer too small!!
            return NULL;
        }
        *--p = "0123456789"[number % 10];
        number /= 10;
    }

    return p;
}

int main()
{
    char buf[20];
    printf("%s\n", my_itoa(buf, sizeof(buf), 123));
}
```

Comment: Wish I could give more +1, this is great! Thank you.